# Is it confirmed as to who attacked the settlement?

Tags: star-wars, the-book-of-boba-fett

In the third episode of *The Book of Boba Fett*, [TV Tropes notes that, near the end of the episode](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Recap/TheBookOfBobaFettS1E3TheStreetsOfMosEspa):

> When Boba returns to the village, he finds it burned to the ground and the people slaughtered by the sand raiders.

Is it confirmed that that is who attacked the settlement? I don't remember any evidence in the episode of who the attackers were, but I acknowledge that I might have missed something, or there might have been a Disney press release that made things more clear.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> I don't remember any evidence in the episode of who the attackers were

You may remember seeing a logo daubed on the Tuskens' camp; the same logo that Boba saw the speeder gang painting on the farm they raided in episode 1 (before Boba beat them up and stole their speeders at Tosche Station in episode 2).

Commenters have kindly pointed out that the gang are [the Kintan Striders](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Kintan_Striders), who, according to the Pyke representative, had already been paid protection money for their Dune Sea spice transport.

Of course, anyone can paint a logo on something, so decide for yourself whether this counts as "confirmed". As also mentioned in the comments, in episode 4, a newly-rescued Fennec Shand expresses doubt that the gang could have defeated the Tuskens on their own.

Comment: Note that the gang's name is the Kintan Striders: https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Kintan_Striders

Comment: I had forgotten that. It is kind of funny that the same gang that he stole the speeders from, apparently randomly, also just happens to be the gang that the Pikes are working with.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Well, we don’t actually know they’re working with the Pikes; it might have just been revenge for the speeder theft. But if they are, they operate in the desert that the Pikes transport spice through, so perhaps not a shocker.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite The Pyke representative says the Kintan Striders collected protection money for that region of the Dune Sea, so the Pykes were at least paying the Striders for something. Unless the Pyke was lying...

Comment: @SpaceWolf1701 Ah right right, okay that makes sense.

Comment: Part of my confusion was that I was reading the "sand raiders" as referring to one of the other (more warlike) Tusken tribes. But yeah, my assumption at this time is that the Pykes themselves wiped out the tribe for the effrontery of attacking them and then trying to shake them down.

Comment: And in Episode 4, Shand does point out that it seems odd that a speeder gang would be able to take down an entire Tusken tribe like that, which further suggests that it was a more dangerous enemy.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - kind of a reverse echo of "It looks like Sandpeople did this, all right. Look, here are Gaffi sticks, Bantha tracks. It's just I never heard of them hitting anything this big before....Ben Kenobi: They didn't. But we are meant to think they did."

Answer (score 8):

As of episode 7, it is confirmed that the Pyke syndicate is behind the slaughter of the Tusken Raiders, using the bikers as a scapegoat.

> **Mok Shaiz**: [Boba Fett] used to live among a Tusken Raider tribe in the desert.
> **Pyke Leader**: They no longer exist.
> **Mok Shaiz**: Are you sure?
> **Pyke Leader**: Yes. We destroyed them ourselves.
> **Cad Bane**: Does Fett know that?
> **Pyke Leader**: He has no idea. He thinks they were killed by Nikto speed bikers. We left evidence behind to encourage such a conclusion.